# My wall is losing details

Tags: modeling

I have added material to this wall, and it has missed all the details, but I still can see the details in edit mode...

[image]

[image]

Comment: right click > Shade Flat or keep Shade Smooth and into the Data panel >Normals, activate the Auto Smooth option?

Comment: @moonboots Or right click > _Shade Auto Smooth_.

Comment: Oh yes I'm so old school  ;)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks guys~ I found the answer when I turned off the auto smooth in normals box. Maybe the reason that is I pressed “alt + L”.

Comment: @moonboots Thx a lot